# Fill Ellipse based on percentage

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone, ellipse

I have created Ellipse in XAML.

Here is the code :

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
   <Ellipse Width="400" Stroke="DodgerBlue" Height="400" StrokeThickness="75" Fill="Transparent">
   </Ellipse>
 </Grid>
```

Say the Ellipse is 100% if its 20% the blue color should fill only till that and also display the percentage text in the center (empty area) of ellipse.

**EDIT**

I have add text to display in center.

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <Ellipse Width="400" Stroke="DodgerBlue" Height="400" StrokeThickness="75" Fill="Transparent">
</Ellipse>
            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                       Text="20"
                       FontSize="125"/>
        </Grid>
```

**EDIT 2**

Here is what how it looks like i am trying to acheive:

[image]

here the orange color with the 20% fill.

Comment: Do you want to fill the blue border, or the inner - currently transparent - content?

Comment: @Herdo the blue color which is showing totally filled now, should only  fill say if its 20 out of 100(total ellipse), say if 80% then fill 80% ellipse, inner empty should be as is

Comment: You could set the percentage in the `TextBlock.Text` property (you might use a binding, if you're using e.g. mvvm design-pattern) and for the `Ellipse.StrokeThickness` refer to the `TextBlock.Text` property (or the binding), and apply a converter that converts the percentage into a value for the `StrokeThickness`.

Comment: @Herdo this is also fine, like now its filled with Blue color, on top of that fill one more color say red with 20 % or 80%

Comment: Then create a second `Ellipse` above the current, make it's `Fill` transparent and apply the logic described above to this ellpise.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49714/discussion-between-goofy-and-herdo)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an arc control preset in the assembly Microsoft.Expression.Drawing

It has properties like StartAngle and EndAngle which could be well manipulated accordingly.

```
 <es:Arc x:Name="arc" ArcThickness="3" ArcThicknessUnit="Pixel" EndAngle="360" Fill="Black" Height="270" Canvas.Left="101.94" Stroke="Black" StartAngle="0" UseLayoutRounding="False" Width="269.941" Canvas.Top="12" />
```

Now what you could do using this control is : Just take two similar arcs One superimposing the other,
color the below one(1st arc) with Blue and give start and end angle properties to the red color arc(2nd arc) which would make your layout look like the way it is mentioned in design two.

**Raw Usage:**

```
<Canvas x:Name="canvas1" Margin="0,10,0,0" Height="300" Width="480" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
<es:Arc x:Name="arc" ArcThickness="3" ArcThicknessUnit="Pixel" Fill="Black" Height="100" Canvas.Left="0" Stroke="Blue" UseLayoutRounding="False" Width="100" Canvas.Top="0"/>
</Canvas>
<es:Arc x:Name="arc" ArcThickness="3" EndAngle="120" StartAngle="0" ArcThicknessUnit="Pixel" Fill="Blue" Height="100" Canvas.Left="0" Stroke="Blue" UseLayoutRounding="False" Width="100" Canvas.Top="0"/>
</Canvas>
```

Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.expression.shapes.arc%28v=expression.40%29.aspx) link as well

Comment: can you please elaborate , what is es ? and how my layout should look like ?

Comment: es is just the reference taken on the top of the xaml page :  xmlns:es="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Expression.Shapes;assembly=Microsoft.Expression.Drawing"

Comment: Can you please show me how my grid looks like ? i am confused, your solution seems to work

Comment: take a canvas control and put two arcs of same dimensions and same positional coordinates in that with the below one completely filled and the above one partially filled depending upon the angle values.

Comment: I am so sorry Aman as i am new to WP8 i have no idea how to do this, and how to use or create canvas control

Answer (score 2):

User control version would consist of two parts: XAML + code-behind.
XAML part:

```
<UserControl
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Project.CustomControls"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:Interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity" xmlns:Core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="40"
d:DesignWidth="40">


<Grid Width="40" Height="40">
    <Ellipse StrokeThickness="3" Stroke="#FF89CE25"/>
    <Path Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="2" x:Name="arcPath">
        <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry>
                <PathFigure StartPoint="20,1">
                    <ArcSegment x:Name="myArc" SweepDirection="Clockwise" IsLargeArc="True" Point="20,1"/>
                </PathFigure>
            </PathGeometry>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
</Grid>
```

Code-behind file (short version, no fluff):

```
public sealed partial class MyCustomControl : UserControl
{


public double ProgressValue
{
    get { return (double)GetValue(ProgressValueProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ProgressValueProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ProgressValue.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty ProgressValueProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ProgressValue", typeof(double), typeof(MyCustomControl), new PropertyMetadata(0.0, OnProgressValueChanged));

private static void OnProgressValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //throw new NotImplementedException();
    MyCustomControl circularProgressBar = d as MyCustomControl;
    if (circularProgressBar != null)
    {
        double r = 19;
        double x0 = 20;
        double y0 = 20;
        circularProgressBar.myArc.Size = new Size(19, 19);
        double angle = 90 - (double)e.NewValue / 100 * 360;
        double radAngle = angle * (PI / 180);
        double x = x0 + r * Cos(radAngle);
        double y = y0 - r * Sin(radAngle);

        if (circularProgressBar.myArc != null)
        {
            circularProgressBar.myArc.IsLargeArc = ((double)e.NewValue >= 50);
            circularProgressBar.myArc.Point = new Point(x, y);
        }
    }
}

public MyCustomControl()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
}
```

}

Now, you can throw your CustomControl into any place in your XAML and bind the ProgressValue property to the respective data source. The arc would redraw itself and will fill the Ellipse shape proportionally to the value (a value from 0-100).